# Which likelihood function for ML estimate of continuous variable?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Let's say my data consists of the counts of the following words in a text. I can then estimate the probabilities of occurrences of these words using MLE:

```
+------+-------+-------+
| word | count | p_hat |
+------+-------+-------+
| ant  |     5 | 0.1   |
| dog  |    30 | 0.6   |
| fish |    10 | 0.2   |
| cat  |     5 | 0.1   |
+------+-------+-------+
```

The likelihood function would be given by:

$L(p) = p(ant)^{count(ant)} \times p(dog)^{count(dog)} \times p(fish)^{count(fish)}  \times p(cat)^{count(cat)}$

Now, assume this data has been mapped to the range [0,5] (or any mapping that would produce fractional values) and sent to a receiver:

```
+------+-------+
| word | value |
+------+-------+
| ant  |   0.5 |
| dog  |     3 |
| fish |     1 |
| cat  |   0.5 |
+------+-------+
```

Would it be wrong for the receiver to estimate the probabilities of these categories by maximizing the same likelihood function? My question is specifically about the values no longer being counts, as it's assumed by the multinomial likelihood.

Comment: (1) It depends on exactly what this "mapping" is. Could you tell us what it is? (2) Although you might get the same *estimates*, in many applications it is of equal or greater importance to calculate the uncertainties of those estimates.  You will surely get that wrong if you don't use the actual counts.

Comment: Trying to use the MDL principle to select a tree cut model, as in [Li & Abe's paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=972734). There, dataset is a set of observations of a number of words, each word is a leaf in a hierarchy of classes (wordnet). A tree cut model is a set of classes representing (dominating) the leaves. Prob. of a class is estimated through MLE; the likelihood of a model is given by the multinomial likelihood I mentioned. In my app., the data consists of areas (instead of counts) of a [treemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) visualization. All rest is the same.

Comment: My implementation works very well in practice. But I'm writing a report on this, so I'm not sure I'm really using a valid likelihood function, since my data is no longer multinomial. The "data" is actually transformed from the raw counts to areas (proportions are kept). Then I'm using MDL to select the tree cut model that provides the best estimation of these areas.

Comment: If the mapping is linear (and order preserving, with zero intercept) you will get the ML estimate--but you will not be using the actual likelihood, so virtually no other operation you apply, such as finding a score, computing the information, computing the variance matrix, etc., will be correct.  So where I'm looking for clarification concerns whether you are merely optimizing what is essentially a power of the likelihood, or if you are going beyond that and using any other part of the ML machinery.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. I'm calculating the likelihood as $\prod_{i=1}^{k}{\hat{P}(w)}^{A(C_i)}$, where $A(C_i)$ is the area of the class $C_i$. Li and Abe calculates it as $\prod_{i=1}^{k}{\hat{P}(w)}^{f(C_i)}$, where $f(C_i)$ is the frequency of the class $C_i$. In both cases, $\hat{P}(w)$ is obtained by normalizing $\hat{P}(C)$ over $|C|$. All I need to make sure is that the same model would be selected by ML using either approach (raw or area mapping); not interested in the actual estimates. The mapping is linear. Is there a formal name for this function, if it isn't a likelihood function?

Comment: I am looking at some slides of a course taught recently by Brad Carlin.  He refers to such an object as a "conditional power prior" and a "historical likelihood."  It's basically the equivalent of the log likelihood that has been multiplied by a factor to downweight it.  In your case, the multiplier would be the common factor that converts frequencies to areas.  (If there is no such common factor, then I have misunderstood and your results will be all wrong.)  Carlin refers to "Ibrahim and Chen, 2000" but unfortunately neglected to supply the full reference.